# Professor Hawking's March 31st Funeral

Tags: discussion

The funeral service for Professor Hawking has been scheduled to take place at 2:00 pm (1300 GMT) on March 31. ([One source](https://www.news18.com/news/tech/stephen-hawkings-funeral-set-for-march-31-1695443.html).)
 Should we schedule a special event in the regular chat room or create a new room?

Comment: The sources I'm reading say that the March 31 funeral will be a private event, and suggest that there will be a public event at a later date when his ashes are interred at Westminster Abbey.

Comment: theres been a lot of discussion/ reverence/ tribute already in the room. lots of starred items & recent discussion in biweekly mtg. maybe there is some cyber or social media place (outside of SE) to show respects or "like" or something on facebook or twitter. https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?room=71&q=hawking

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Echoing rob in the comments, I think it would be indecent to turn what is primarily a private event into a public one. If there is a public event related to his passing on some other date, I would be all for following it along in the chat.